# Microsoft Access applying 1 function to all fields automatically

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a form that keeps track of assigned patient equipment. I have it set so that any changes made to text fields on the form automatically move down to the "comments" section of the form (this is done so that any changes made are documented in case the user forgets to manually document changes). I have a sub that I wrote that accomplishes this that I am currently calling for every single text field. This works but is messy.

Is there a way to apply the sub to all the fields in one procedure without calling it for every individual field? Code is below, please let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
Private Sub pPEMoveValue(sField)
'Moves the old field value down to the comments section automatically

Dim sOrigValue As String
Dim sCommentValue As String

sOrigValue = sField
sCommentValue = Nz(mPEComments, "")

Me.mPEComments = sCommentValue & vbNewLine & sOrigValue

End Sub


Private Sub sPEBatCharger_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)

pPEMoveValue (Nz(Me.sPEBatCharger.OldValue, ""))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with to do what you are looking to do.  I took advantage of the MS Access [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216030(v=office.12).aspx) system.  You can add tags to your controls so you can sort of "Group" them.

First put the form in design view and adjust the tag for all of the fields you want to record to say "Notes".

Then in the Form's `BeforeUpdate` even you would add this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Call FindControlsForComments(Me.Form)
End Sub
```

Then you would use this function to find any fields that have the "Notes" tag and run it through the function you created:

```vb
Public Function FindControlsForComments(frm As Form)

    Dim ctrl As Access.Control

    For Each ctrl In frm

        'If the control is tagged for notes
        If ctrl.Tag = "Notes" Then

            'If the old value is different than the current value 
            If Nz(ctrl.OldValue, "") <> Nz(ctrl.Value, "") Then

                'Add to comment
                Call pPEMoveValue(Nz(ctrl.Value, ""))
            End If
        End If

    Next ctrl

End Function
```

You may have to adjusted this slightly to work with your system but this has worked well for me.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I had to add a DoCmd.Requery to the code for my save button so that the form reflected the update immediately after saving, but other than that it did exactly what I wanted it to. Thank you.

Comment: @Alisa No problem, glad I could help.